# xml element prefix alternative

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

When writing the element, is there a way to address specific elements from some namespace by not using a prefix, e.g. some kind of long name that includes the namespace joined with the element name everywhere?
As I understand it, prefix is used as a convenience.

For example, can this

```
<new:element xlmns:new='urn:some:custom:ns'>text...</new:element>
```

be represented without prefix form?

Comment: In what context? When writing the element? When searching a DOM using the W3C DOM API? Something else?

Comment: edit: question is put in context

Comment: XPath 3.1 has a context-free syntax: `Q{uri}local`. It would be nice if this could be used everywhere, including within XML instances, but sadly that's not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `xmlns` attribute on every element.

```
<element xlmns='urn:some:custom:ns'>text...</element>
```

… although I believe this approach prevents you from using attributes from a namespace other than the one the element belongs to.

Comment: right, in that case the namespace will become a default one. There is no way of bundling all required data within element name, something like <urn:some:custom:ns:element /> ?

Comment: "than the namespace will become a default one" — Yes. And if you want to change it again, you use `xmlns` again. It's inconvenient. That's why namespace prefixes exist as a convenience.

Comment: "There is no way of bundling all required data within element name" — That's what the namespace prefixes are for.